# regex for when delimiter may also be in the value

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that is comprised of several key/value pairs and I want to extract the key/values from the string using regex (in Python in my case). The key/values are always one word except one case that I describe in next. The delimiter between the key/value pairs is `:`, and there may or may not be one/several spaces before or after the colon), so something like this:

`key1: value1 this_is_not_part_of_any_key_or_value key2:value2`.

The part that makes it a bit difficult is that the values could have colon in them too, but if they do, they are always guaranteed to be inside `[]` and in that case they could be more than one word. So for instance, `[123:45 * & foo 34:abc]` is a valid value, but `123:abd` is not a valid value.

So for a string like:
`key1: value1  this_is_not_key_or_value key2 : [123:bcd * & abc:23]`
I want to extract these as the key/value pairs:

- `key1` and `value1`
- `key2` and `[123:bcd * & abc:23]`

Can someone help me with the proper regex string to do this? or maybe it is easier to just write a few lines of code to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement straightforwardly translates to

```
import re

re.findall(r'(\b[^:\d\s][^:\s]*): *(\[[^][]*\]|\S+)', your_data)
```

To slightly unpack this,

- `\b` anchors the beginning of the match to a word boundary, so as to avoid a match that starts in the middle of a token.
- `[^:\d\s]` matches a character which is not a colon, a digit, or a whitespace character. We allow this to be followed by zero or more characters which are not colon or whitespace. We capture this as the key.
- The previous needs to be followed by a colon and optional spaces, which we ignore, and
- Either square brackets containing characters which are not square brackets, or characters which are not whitespace.

  - To further unpack this, `\[` matches a literal opening square bracket and `\]` a closing one; `[^][]` is a negated character class containing the characters `]` and `[`, i.e. it matches any character which is not a square bracket, and we accept an arbitrarily long sequence of these, including an empty sequence.

Demo: https://ideone.com/NcjDQ7